# Why does mingw issue a warning for printf("%d",x) when x is a signed char?

Tags: c, char, printf, mingw

When I compile

```
signed char x=1;
printf("%d",x);
```

with mingw, I get the following warning:

```
format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'signed char *' [-Wformat=]
```

I am aware that `%d` prints decimal integers and not characters, and also that I am passing a (signed) char pointer as a second argument. But shouldn't `x` get promoted to an int and then be printed correctly?

Why does mingw warn me here?

EDIT: I'm sorry, this warning actually is produced by a scanf call:

```
signed char x;
scanf("%d",&x);
```

(The other code gets compiled without warnings.)

I assume this is because scanf will try to write the number of bytes for an int, whereas I have only reserved storage for a char, which may produce a runtime error...?

Comment: The warning actually says you are passing `int *`(a pointer or array name), not char. Are you sure this is the code that produces the warning?

Comment: @BlueMoon read the error messages again - says **expecting** `int*`, **got** `signed char*`. Though I agree, doesn't correspond to a `printf` call.

Comment: @isedev Right. Still I don't think, this code produces the warning. I think, DevSolar is right here (i.e. scanf call, that we can't see, produces this warning).

Comment: @@Blue Moon and Wumpus: You are perfectly right. Sorry. I've mixed it up with a scanf call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the argument has to match the corresponding conversion specifier or the behavior is *undefined*, meaning the compiler doesn't have to handle the situation any particular way; the fact that you're even getting a warning is because the compiler writers went above and beyond the requirements of the standard (and because it's such a *common* error).

The problem is that `%d` specifies that the corresponding argument points to an object of type `int`, which will most likely be larger than an object of type `char`.  Your `scanf` call is assuming it has `sizeof (int)` bytes to write to, but the object you're writing to is only 1 byte wide (`sizeof (char) == 1` by definition).  One possible consequence is that the wrong byte gets written to, leading to *at best* unexpected input.

For example, assume `sizeof (int)` == 4, the address of `x` is `0x4000`, and that this is a *big-endian* architecture, meaning the most significant byte in a multi-byte type is stored at the specified address.  This is how memory looks after your declaration of and initialization of `x`:

```
         +----+
 0x4000: | 01 |    <-- x
         +----+
 0x4001: | ?? |
         +----+
 0x4002: | ?? |
         +----+
 0x4003: | ?? |
         +----+
```

where `??` represents an unknown byte value.  Now, assume in the `scanf` call, you enter a `2`.  Because the conversion specifier is `%d`, the `scanf` call will assume it's writing to an `int` object, meaning that your memory will look like this:

```
         +----+
 0x4000: | 00 |    <-- x
         +----+
 0x4001: | 00 |
         +----+
 0x4002: | 00 |
         +----+
 0x4003: | 02 |
         +----+
```

When you examine `x`, it will contain `0`, which is not what you expected.  Furthermore, memory outside of `x` has been modified, which may potentially lead to other problems.

Again, this is *one possible outcome* based on specific architecture details; on a little-endian architecture, it would appear to work because the least-significant byte would be at `0x4000`, but you're still writing outside the bounds of that object.

**Edit**

As DevSolar points out, you should be using the `%hhd` conversion specifier if you intend to read numerical values and store them to a `char` object (i.e., you want to store the *value* `2` and not the *character* `'2'`).  If you want to store single character values (`'2'`, `'a'`, `'?'`, etc.), use the `%c` conversion specifier.

Answer (score -1):

It warns you because you *should* have written...

```
signed char x = 1;
printf( "%hhd", x ); // 'hh' length modifier to indicate char argument
```

Also, see the comment by Blue Moon: The error message talking about *pointer* types indicates `scanf()`, not `printf()`, and a wrong length modifier in `scanf()` is downright lethal (writing `sizeof( int )` bytes to a place that can take only `sizeof( signed char )`...).

In case it's not obvious, the length modifier works for `scanf()` as well:

```
signed char x;
if ( scanf( "%hhd", &x ) == 1 )
{
    // do yourself a favor and DO check scanf() success
    // before acting on the results
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `hh`?

Comment: @potrzebie: Precision of expression. And because length modifiers are much superior to casting or ignoring compiler warnings. (Casts don't work if the argument is larger than `int`, and they don't work with `scanf()`. Ignoring compiler warnings *never* "works".)

Comment: You don't need `%hhd` for `printf` (not even for "Precision of expression"); you do need it for `scanf`. This `%hhd` is non-idiomatic, unnecessary and induces FUD.

Comment: @anatolyg: I disagree. Using the correct length modifier in any kind of format string, no matter if it's `printf()` or `scanf()`, no matter if it's implicitly handled by integer promotion or not, is good coding practice IMHO. (Pretty much the same way as adding code comments is not *necessary*, but certainly helpful.) You are free to think otherwise, but I stand by this.

Comment: @DevSolar When `x` is a `signed char`, and you try to pass `x` to `printf`, what you are actually passing is an `int` value. That's just how default argument promotions work. By what logic, then, is `%hhd` *the* correct length modifier?

Comment: @hvd: By definition of the language standard.

Comment: @DevSolar The language standard doesn't require `%hhd` for `printf`. It allows it, but it also allows `%d`, and it doesn't say one is more correct than the other. That's only you.

Comment: @hvd If argument promotion rules should change in future standards, code using the correct size modifier won't have to be changed. `%d` for char and short relies on the promotion rules.

Comment: @potrzebie Changes to argument promotion rules would break any code that uses `va_arg` for shorter-than-`int` values, including custom implementations of `printf`. If the standards committee would decide to break such an enormous amount of existing code, there's no telling whether `%hhd` would be kept working. Also, `%hhd` is new in C99 and still less widely supported than `%d`, which prior to C99 was the *only* correct way to print such values.

Comment: @hvd: You fail to realize that we are arguing from two completely opposide approaches. No, `%hhd` is not *necessary*. Neither are comments, `assert()` statements, structured programming, and many other things that are, nevertheless, considered **good practice**. And since `%hhd` **is necessary** in the case of `scanf()`, I consider using it in `printf()` as well to be in accordance with the principle of least surprise.

Comment: @DevSolar That's a perfectly reasonable point of view, and that answers my earlier question. By what logic? No, not by definition of the language standard (because as stated already, that's not what the language standard defines), but because of your personal opinion that the format specifiers to `printf` should match those to `scanf` as closely as possible. I'm not saying it's not valid, but I think you'll find there isn't general agreement on it.

Comment: @hvd: I've found you don't even get general agreement on the usefulness of comments, so... yeah. ;-)